# How to make the length of X and Y axis the same when using the DevExpress Chart 3D control?

Tags: charts, devexpress, axis

I am studying DevExpress WPF Chart 3D control recently and I modified the example code to generate the following chart.[![chart picture][1]][1]

My code snippet is

```cs
var points = new List<TestPoint>();
for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 360; j++)
    {
        points.Add(new TestPoint()
        {
          X = i,
          Y = j,
          Z = new Random(i * j % 10).NextDouble() * 10 + 100
        });
    }
}
...
DoubleCollection mapX = new DoubleCollection(xArray.Length);
DoubleCollection mapY = new DoubleCollection(yArray.Length);
DoubleCollection values = new DoubleCollection(xArray.Length * yArray.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < xArray.Length; i++)
{
    mapX.Add(xStart + i * xStep);
    for (int j = 0; j < yArray.Length; j++)
    {
        mapY.Add(yStart + j * yStep);
        double value = array[i, j];
        values.Add(value);
    }
}
MapY = mapX;
MapX = mapY;
MapValues = values;
```

How to make the length of the X-axis and Y-axis the same so the XY plane will be a square?
Any help would be appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PorZ8.png

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Setting the AspectRatio of Chart3DControl to "1 1 1" works well.